# Horizontal lines in dataplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to add only horizontal help lines in my plot and not a grid. 
So I decided to add lines with \draw[very thin] but somehow these lines are different from each other. I want them to be all the same. 
I hope someone can help me. 
I'm using the dataplot package to load a *.csv file and draw the plot.

This is what my code looks like

```
\DTLloaddb{kiting}{Abbildungen/Kapitel_05/kitingplot.csv}
\DTLloaddb{kitingdxcs}{Abbildungen/Kapitel_05/kitingdxcsplot.csv}
\begin{figure}[htpb]
\centering
\setcounter{DTLplotroundXvar}{0}
\renewcommand*{\DTLplotatendtikz}{%
\draw[very thin, gray] (0,60) -- (1000,60);
\draw[very thin, gray] (0,65) -- (1000,65);
\draw[very thin, gray] (0,70) -- (1000,70);
\draw[very thin, gray] (0,75) -- (1000,75);
\draw[very thin, gray] (0,80) -- (1000,80);
\draw[very thin, gray] (0,85) -- (1000,85);
\draw[very thin, gray] (0,90) -- (1000,90);
\draw[very thin, gray] (0,95) -- (1000,95);
\draw[very thin, gray,] (0,100) -- (1000,100);
}
\DTLplot{kiting,kitingdxcs}{x=Spiele, y=Siege, style=lines, linecolors={red, blue}, bounds={0, 40, 1000, 100}, xlabel={Spiele}, ylabel={Gewonnene Spiele in \%}, legend=south, legendlabels={Kiting, Kiting DXCS}, height = 3in, yticgap=5}
\caption{Kiting Experiment}
\end{figure}
```

An this is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
    \begin{axis}[ ymajorgrids=true]%THIS WILL DRAW THE HORIZONTAL LINES
      \addplot table [col sep=comma] {data.csv};
     \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: in your preamble: \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}